# Laravel route model binding 500 error

Tags: laravel, error-handling, routes, laravel-5.3

I have a route like this

Route::get('/articles/{article}', 'ArticleController@show');

All works but if you put mydomain.com/articles/non-existent where the article name does not exist I get an internal error.

Why does that not return a 404 or how do I get it to return a 404 or how do I handle the internal error to display a page without having it mess up the 404 error handling?

I currently have this in my Exceptions/Handler.php

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if ($this->isHttpException($exception)) {
        return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
    }else{
        return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);
    }
}
```

This always returns the 500 page even if it is just a normal 404 error.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score -1):

Try to find out what type of exception it is because isHttpException is very generic. Also in your case it is not even an NotFoundHttpException since it is not returning 404.If your are getting 500 it is definitely because of an errorException.

```
    //This will let you know if your dealing with 404 or not

    if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        return response()->view('front.missing', [], 404);
    }
    else 
    {

      return response()->view('errors.500', [], 500);

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The route model binding works if there is a route. It does show a 500 error if the route does not exist. I am getting the custom error page but it shows the 500 error page even on pages that don't use the route model binding and should just return the 404 error page.

Answer (score -1):

You should throw an exception on your controller. So you can see the 404 page.

```
$article = Article::find(article_id); // or with slug
If(!$article){
    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  This should work but it seems the Exception/Handler.php runs before it hits the controller.  I am still getting the  custom 500 page I created and not the 404